# Is that possible to select all elements that does not match a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a table with lots of rows.

I would like to select all rows that does not match some selector.

For example:

```
$('#my_table tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".class_a.class_b[my_param='" + my_value + "']").length > 0) {
        $(this).do_something();
    }
});
```

Is that possible to do the same in easier way ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ perhaps is of some use?

Comment: Gotcha: When you remove these elements, it may not work if they contain children which you want to keep. In that case, first search the elements which you want to keep, `.detach()` them, `.remove()` all `children()` or `.contents()` from root element, `.append()` detached elements to root element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery's [`:not()`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). It excludes elements from the current selection set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_table tr').not('.class_a').each(function(){
   // do something
}
);
```

the above code will select all rows that are in table with ID='**my_table**' and whose classname is not '**class_a**' . Is this what you needed ?